# How to add a custom polyfill to an angular-cli project?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, polyfills

I need the ability to easily sort collections and I've chosen to extend the Array primitive. I realize this is considered bad practice in most cases, but this will be used only internally (not a shared lib). No matter what approach I've tried I'm not getting a working result even though it works as expected [in the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Array%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%24sortBy(sortKey%3A%20string)%3A%20T%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%24sortKey%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%24reversed%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(!Array.prototype.%24sortBy)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Object.defineProperties(Array.prototype%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'%24sortBy'%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20function%20(sortKey)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(sortKey%20%3D%3D%3D%20this.%24sortKey)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.reverse()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.%24reversed%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.%24reversed%20%3D%20false%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.%24sortKey%20%3D%20sortKey%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.sort(function%20(a%2C%20b)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20this%20will%20be%20replaced%20by%20a%20more%20complex%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20alphanumeric%2Fnatural%20sort%20method%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(a%5BsortKey%5D%20%3C%20b%5BsortKey%5D)%20%7B%20return%20-1%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(a%5BsortKey%5D%20%3E%20b%5BsortKey%5D)%20%7B%20return%201%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'%24sortKey'%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20writable%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20null%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'%24reversed'%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20writable%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20false%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20people%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7Bname%3A%20'dick'%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7Bname%3A%20'alice'%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7Bname%3A%20'zed'%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7Bname%3A%20'barry'%7D%0D%0A%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20original%0D%0Aconsole.log(%60Original%3A%20%24%7BJSON.stringify(people)%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20sorted%0D%0Alet%20people1%20%3D%20people.slice().%24sortBy('name')%0D%0Aconsole.log(%60Sorted%3A%20%24%7BJSON.stringify(people1)%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20reversed%0D%0Alet%20people2%20%3D%20people.slice().%24sortBy('name')%3B%0D%0Apeople2.%24sortBy('name')%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(%60Reversed%3A%20%24%7BJSON.stringify(people2)%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A).

I've tried adding the polyfill inline in `/src/polyfills.ts` but that gives me a "*TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property*" in the console when I call the `$sortBy` method...

```ts
declare global {
  interface Array<T> {
    $sortBy(sortKey:string): T[];
  }
}

if (!Array.prototype['$sortBy']) {

  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, '$sortBy', {
    value: function(sortKey) {
      return this.sort( function(a, b) { // TypeError here???
        if (a[sortKey] < b[sortKey]) { return -1; }
        if (a[sortKey] > b[sortKey]) { return 1; }
        return 0;
      });
    }
  })

}
```

I've also tried adding a plain javascript version via npm and importing but that gives me the same type error. What's the secret???

*/node_modules/my-polyfills/sortBy.js*

```js
if (!Array.prototype.$sortBy) {
  Object.defineProperties(Array.prototype, {
    '$sortBy': {
      value: function (sortKey) {
        return this.sort(function (a, b) {
          if (a[sortKey] < b[sortKey]) {
            return -1;
          }
          if (a[sortKey] > b[sortKey]) {
            return 1;
          }
          return 0;
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

*.angular-cli.json*

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": { ... },
  "apps": [
    {
      ...,
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/my-polyfills/sortBy.js",
        "../node_modules/moment/moment.js"
      ],
      ...
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: have you tried: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37640785/how-do-you-add-polyfills-to-globals-in-typescript-modules ?

Comment: Thanks @AhmedMusallam! That fixed my intellisense error. I've updated my example to include `declare global`. However, the type error still remains :(

Comment: are you using **both** the `/node_modules/my-polyfills/sortBy.js` file And the first file which I assume is TS? this error `TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property` happens when you try to assign a non-writable property to something. In this case if you define `Arrays.prototype.$sortBy` THEN you try to modify that `$sortBy` by assigning it to a new function, you'll get that error. I ask because when I try your code in the browser, the first snippet, it works just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have an generated app on angular cli 1.0.0. While I think your issue has nothing to do with the version, I have taken your code below and appended it to `src/polyfills.ts` it works as expected:

```
declare global {
  interface Array<T> {
    $sortBy(sortKey:string): T[];
  }
}

if (!Array.prototype['$sortBy']) {

  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, '$sortBy', {
    value: function(sortKey) {
      return this.sort( function(a, b) { // TypeError here???
        if (a[sortKey] < b[sortKey]) { return -1; }
        if (a[sortKey] > b[sortKey]) { return 1; }
        return 0;
      });
    }
  })
}
```

in one of my components I added:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = a.$sortBy('');
console.log(b)
```

I did not see the error in the console and array `a` was printed just fine.

I think the issue you are having is because you have the code above in your `src/polyfills.ts` **AND** you have included the same polyfill in `/node_modules/my-polyfills/sortBy.js` and added that to `scripts` section of your `.angular-cli`

You should add either or, not both. I recommend the former, but in it's own file and not appended to `polyfills.ts`

this error `TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property` happens when you try to assign a non-writable property to something else. By using [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) you are making `$sortBy` non-writable. You defined Arrays.prototype.$sortBy THEN you try to modify that $sortBy by assigning it to a new function, hence you get the error.